# The best approach to write a large file using Spring Boot and AWS

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, design-patterns, aws-sdk

Today I have a process where I generate a file, write this in local disk and after I do a upload to S3. But now I want to change this process, I want to do the upload this file while I am writing it by stream. I am using *aws-java-sdk*, but I don't have success to implent this approuch.

Simple code to illustrate what I want to do:

```
for (int i = 5000; i > 0; i--) {
                Upload upload;
                //create temp file
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("teste", ".txt");

                //write
                OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                Writer osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                bw.write("Test-Upload");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();

                //upload
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
                ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                objectMetadata.setContentLength(tempFile.length());
                upload = tm.upload(bucketName, key.concat(tempFile.getName()), fis, objectMetadata);
                upload.waitForUploadResult();
            }
```

Today my mean problem is that I load the file in memory when I write and load it again when a send to S3, I want to improve this process, but I don't know if is the best way and/or is possible, becaseu in my searchings I don't found many case how this.

Answer (score 2):

If it's text file with data You can use [Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/). It can recive Your data and stream it to S3 bucket.

```
public void publish(String data) {
        AmazonKinesisFirehose amaznonFirehose = amaznonFirehose();
        Record record = new Record().withData(ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes()));
        PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
        putRecordRequest.setDeliveryStreamName("your-stream-name");
        putRecordRequest.setRecord(record);
        PutRecordResult putRecordResult = amaznonFirehose.putRecord(putRecordRequest);

    }

    private AmazonKinesisFirehose amaznonFirehose() {
        BasicAWSCredentials basicAwsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY,
                SECRET_KEY);
        return AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.builder().withRegion(REGION)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAwsCredentials)).build();
    }
```

Just instead of crating TXT file publish  Your text into stream of Firehose.

Comment: I will analyze this option, thanks for your answer. I will post here if I implement this approach.